# For Each IP Loop

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and am trying to write a script that will search a network range, map a network drive for each IP, and search for a specific file on the machine in a specific folder.

I have the IPrange part working, as well as the mapping and searching. Problem is that the script wants to run all at once, which causes a problem as the mapped drive is still in use.

I need it to be able to run the whole script once, then move on to the next IP address. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

```
import fnmatch
import os
from netaddr import *

IPSet(IPRange('192.168.25.47', '192.168.25.50'))

for ip in IPSet(IPRange('192.168.25.47', '192.168.25.50')):
    os.system(r'net use z: \\%s\c$' % ip)
for file in os.listdir('z:\Windows\system32'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'bob.exe'):
        print (ip, file)
os.system(r"net use Z: /delete /Y")
```

Comment: Is that really the indentation you're using, or is this a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indentation matters a lot in Python. You need to indent part of your code so it runs once in each iteration of the outermost `for` loop, not after it has finished:

```
import fnmatch
import os
from netaddr import *
for ip in IPSet(IPRange('192.168.25.47', '192.168.25.50')):
    os.system(r'net use z: \\%s\c$' % ip)
    for file in os.listdir(r'z:\Windows\system32'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'bob.exe'):
            print (ip, file)
    os.system(r"net use Z: /delete /Y")
```